# Why my flutter app launches slowly on my real device but quickly on simulator?

Tags: flutter

So here is the issue I am having. I am building a flutter app that is medium sized. It is qr-code generator and scanner app. When I run my app on my iphone it opens the app and shows totally white blank screen for like a minute or more and then shows the UI. However, when I run the app on ios simulator, it works just fine,like not that long white blank screen. I can not figure out why. For your information, my device is iPhone 13 Pro Max, iOS 17.3.

I have tried to update my Mac and iphone. Also tried to restart both of them multiple times. But nothing did work. Could not find any feasible solution also.

**UPDATE**:
The problem was with my phone only. I ran the app on the devices and it worked fine.

Comment: What is your flutter & dart version?

Comment: Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 41456452f2 (12 days ago) • 2024-01-25 10:06:23 -0800
Engine • revision f40e976bed
Tools • Dart 3.2.6 • DevTools 2.28.5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the method that is being called before `runApp()` method, you might get some clues there.
Some services like Firebase or such might take some time to initialize and result in blank screen.

Comment: There is no any method called before runApp(). I am not using Firebase also.